# Send money back using Paypal

Tags: paypal

I have application where one can join with amount [10$] [which recurring permonth] , for which he/she can use paypal account or direct payment by visa or credit. I got success for creating recurring profile on paypal in both case [paypal account/visa-creditcard etc]. and at end of month we have to distribute prize

Example:
User1 joins with 10$ [using paypal account]
User2 joins with 10$ [using master card]
User3 joins with 10$ [user visa card]
so on,
Prize distribution
User1 won 20$
User2 won 10$

So my question is, how can i send them these money back? what I am having is recurring profileid generated by paypal can this used in both case [paypal account / cards]?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the MassPay https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay function of Paypal to send money from your Paypal account to theirs if you have a Premier or Business account, but I don't think Paypal supports sending money directly to a 'real' bank account.